# What is point of application of force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

My textbook said that point of application is the exact location at which a force is applied to a body. But I know that there are some forces that their points of application outside the body (like gravity of a ring). In those cases,  force effects into the space (This is clearly absurd). So what is the definition of point of application of force in Newtonian Mechanics ? I really want an answer about this problem.

Comment: How can a force be applied to a body outside of the body? Are you getting mixed up with the concept of a field that exists independent of bodies from which the field exerts a force?

Answer (score 1):

"But I know that there are some forces that their points of application outside the body (like gravity of a ring)"

Each particle of a body has a gravitational force acting on it. The point of application of each force is the particle on which it acts. Let the vector sum of these forces be $\vec F$.

However, if all these forces could be turned off and a single
force equal to $\vec F$ be applied instead, there is one point (the body's *centre of gravity*) at which it could be applied for which the body's motion and the other forces (e.g. contact forces) acting on it will be just the same as before.

As with your ring, it may be that the centre of gravity lies outside the physical material of the body itself. If this worries you, remember that (a) the whole idea of replacing the individual gravitational forces by a single force is just an aid to calculation, (b) if you want to picture the force acting you can, if you wish, think of the actual body as possessing a rigid extension of negligible weight, on which lies the centre of gravity!